# Running total using Sum and Over not working in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a bunch of employees with pay raises. A single employee can have multiple pay raises each raise given for a different reason. An employee cannot have multiple raises with the same reason, so the combination of `EmployeeID` and `RaiseReason` is unique.

I need to keep a running total of each employee's salary after each raise.

So I have:

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, CurrentSalary, RaiseAmount, RaiseReason, 
    CurrentSalary + SUM(RaiseAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, RaiseReason ORDER BY EmployeeID, RaiseReason) AS RunningSalaryTotal
FROM 
    Employees
```

If I run this I don't get a running total, instead it resets the sum for each raise.

For example:

```
EmployeeID   CurrentSalary   RaiseAmount   RaiseReason   RunningSalaryTotal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1         100000          1000        Performance        101000
     1         100000          5000        Promotion          105000
```

The second record should have Running Salary Total as 100000 + 1000 + 5000 = 106000.

If instead I partition by only `EmployeeID`, then the final total is shown for each employee.

For example:

```
EmployeeID   CurrentSalary   RaiseAmount   RaiseReason   RunningSalaryTotal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1         100000          1000        Performance        106000
     1         100000          5000        Promotion          106000
```

Now it's just a total, not a running total.

How do I get the `RunningSalaryTotal` to increment properly for each record?

Comment: If you don't want it to "reset" after each raise, why do you have `RaiseReason` in the `PARTITION BY` clause?

Comment: Also, if you are providing data, provide it as DDL and DML statements or as tabular formatted `text`; that sample data and expected results are almost impossible to understand, and aren't consumable from a DBMS perspective.

Comment: @Larnu as I said, I tried it both with RaiseReason and without. Neither is correct. Without raise reason it doesn't provide a running total for each employee, just a total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT EmployeeID, CurrentSalary, RaiseAmount, RaiseReason
    , CurrentSalary + SUM(RaiseAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID
                                                ORDER BY EmployeeID 
                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningSalaryTotal
FROM Employees
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove raisereason from partition by

```
SELECT EmployeeID, CurrentSalary, RaiseAmount, RaiseReason, CurrentSalary + SUM(RaiseAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY EmployeeID, RaiseReason) AS RunningSalaryTotal
FROM Employees
```

Sql fiddle [code to test](http://t.ly/2nxpO)

Comment: As I stated if I remove RaiseReason then I don't get a running total for each employee, just a total.

Comment: Nope, please check here t.ly/2nxpO

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I just get the total for each employee repeated, even if that employee has multiple raises. Every employee just has the total of their current salary plus all raises for the RunningSalaryTotal. I've even re-run the query without RaiseReason in the PARTITION to check again.

Comment: Did you checked sql fiddle link? because the window by default is rows between unbounded preceding and current row, which we dont need to explicitly mention in this case

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to know why, but for whatever reason it was necessary to explicitly specify unbounded preceding and current row. Once that was included the running total worked. Perhaps a SQL Server configuration issue? Is there some kind of flag that alters the default behavior?

Comment: Looks like the default is actually RANGE between unbounded preceding and current row which would explain why the behavior changed when explicitly specifying ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row. See here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/